# What should I do if I am on fire?

Tags: defiance

I noticed that in Defiance you can roll your character (default <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

If I am on fire, will rolling make it stop?  Do any other [nano effects](http://www.defiancedata.com/page.php?id=15) stop after rolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ["stop, drop and roll"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt7WHdYOtso) still works after the Arkfall. And it does work on other Nano Effects.

You can find this information in game in Intel -> Help -> Combat -> Dive Roll.

I find <kbd>Alt</kbd> awkward to press rapidly with the normal WASD combination, and I tend to hit the Windows key instead, and have remapped it to an extra button on my mouse.